# Integration test of spring stream failed after update to Greenwich

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-cloud-stream

I just upgraded spring boot to 2.1.0.RELEASE and spring cloud stream to Greenwich.SR1.

I have an integration test which autowires MessageCollector, but the context fails to load because there is already a binder created in KafkaBinderConfiguration.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollector]: Factory method 'messageCollector' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder cannot be cast to org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder cannot be cast to org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinder
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollectorAutoConfiguration.messageCollector(MessageCollectorAutoConfiguration.java:35)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollectorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7750c59.CGLIB$messageCollector$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollectorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7750c59$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6fd994de.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollectorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7750c59.messageCollector(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 45 more
```

There's TestSupportBinderConfiguration class which creates a test binder bean, but it's not happening because of its signature:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Binder.class)
public class TestSupportBinderConfiguration {}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you have two binders on the classpath which falls into category of multiple-binding - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-binders. You're mixing Integration testing (with Kafka binder) and simple unit testing (with Test binder). This is not a common practice. Are you saying that the same setup worked before you upgraded?

Comment: Yep, With spring boot 1.4.5 and spring cloud 1.3.0 it worked perfectly. Do you have an example of how should I test the binder on integration test?

Comment: I would not expect integration test to run in the same space as unit tests. In fact we separate them in different projects as well within the framework. Also, I would recommend for unit tests to switch to using the new test binder as it more accurately represents the interaction with the real binder.